# javascript: использование this внутри map с лямбда-функцией

Tags: javascript, map, binding, lambda, this

внутри метода класса использую метод `map` с лямбда-функцией, внутри которой вызывается метод класса:

```
method1 = () => {
   res = arr.map(elem => this.method2(elem));
}
```

но в этом случае `this` как я понял относится к лямбда-функции, а не к классу.

Подскажите как **СОХРАНЯЯ** лямбда-функцию сделать так, чтоб this указывал на класс или хотя бы чтоб до метода класса можно было дотянуться из лямбда-функции

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, у стрелочной функции нет своего контекста this, и он теряется. Поменяйте на обычную, и проверьте поведение.

Comment: Стрелочные функции берут `this` "снаружи", т.к. своего у них нет. https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions#u-strelochnyh-funktsiy-net-this

Comment: @ksa У него тут получается что колбэк стрелка внутри map, ссылается наружу, в method1, но она тоже стрелочная, поэтому ему нечего с него брать. Ему нужно этот method1 сделать обычной функцией, верно?

Comment: @Elmir, ТС не сделал полного примера... Т.ч. точно сказать не получится. Но у него все функции стрелочные - т.ч. `this` будет "где-то выше". А что там у него - х/з...